# Chrome: inline-block, padding-right and right click bug

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am creating a CSS centered horizontal list for our team's site. It's unfinished, but here is a demo of how it looks so far: http://marbleblastultra.tk/welcomeguest.htm

- In Firefox, the list looks how I intend it to look.
- In IE, it's not perfect, but it's nothing that I can't fix later on.
- However, in Chrome, the longer text is overflowing outside of the
  items... until I right click on them...
- or until I uncheck float-right in Chrome's inspector, then check it
  again.

Such a weird, strange behavior. Right clicking? Why? Google searching reveals nothing. Searching this forum reveals nothing about the phenomenon either.

I am using *Chrome 40 for Windows*, but it might happen on different versions too.

What makes this list so complicated and unique is each item's background image. I want the text for each item to be centered both vertically and horizontally inside the background image. Easy enough, but the background images have transparent corners, and I need to use padding to push the text into the middle.

[image: how it should look, in theory]

The above image shows *how each item should look* in the centered horizontal list, with the text centered within the blue area, never on top of the transparent corners (highlighted in green).

[image: what it does look like, right now]

The above image, however, shows *what I see instead* in Chrome right now. The text incorrectly overflows outside of the box. Here is a cleaned up code sample from the test page.

CSS:

```
ul.welcomeguest li {
min-width:150px;
min-height:50px;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:50px;
white-space:nowrap;
display:inline-block;
background:url(images/button_d.png) no-repeat center;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
ul.welcomeguest li div {
display:inline-block;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width:100%" align="center">
<ul class="welcomeguest">
<li><a href="/index.php"><div>Homepage</div></a></li><!--
--><li><div><a href="/login/">Login/Register</a></div></li><!--
--><li><div><a href="/update/mirrors.php">Download Game</a></div></li><!--
--><li><div><a href="/levels/index.php">Download Levels</a></div></li><!--
--><li><div><a href="/lb/view.php">View Leaderboards</a></div></li><!--
--><li><div><a href="/infotutorial/index.php">Info/Tutorials</a></div></li><!--
--><li><a href="/about.php"><div>Contact Locations/About</div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

*How may I reliably add padding-right to a display:inline-block'd element in Chrome, if at all?*

**JSFiddle?** http://jsfiddle.net/mh70zn34/3/

Comment: That's a weird bug. It seems to work in the JSFiddle if I change the padding from a percentage (10%) to a fixed value (2em).

Comment: If only it were that easy. I can't use a fixed value because the image stretches to the length of the text (notice the background-size) and the padding needs to be relative to the background image.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, it works perfectly with a fixed value. The background image does strech to text+padding.

Comment: take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mh70zn34/5/
this is using your code. For the second to last element, it looks fine. But look at the last element. It has edged closer to that transparent area on the image. It wouldn't be such a big deal, except that this style of list is going to be used to display content which users type in and is constantly changing, so it needs to be very flexible. But thanks for the suggestion :) if all else fails, I'll probably end up using that.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry. By the way, you might want to look into border-image for an alternative, keeping background-image for a fallback.

Comment: yeah. Either that or I'll throw semantics to the wind and use a bunch of div's in a row instead, if styling a UL is going to be this difficult. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.welcomeguest li:last-child{
min-width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this solution. Placing this at the end of the code made no visible difference. Giving the last li a class of "last-child" then changing the : to a . made no difference either. Where do I put this so that this will work correctly?

Comment: so you can remove :last-child. but with of li not equal.
Because you have used min-width: 150px;.

Comment: I need the min-width of the li to be 150px, otherwise the background image becomes smaller than its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry :D, Please check it
HMLT : you need remove tag div in

```
<div style="width:100%" align="center">
<ul class="welcomeguest">
<li><a href="/index.php">Homepage</a></li>
<li><a href="/login/">Login/Register</a></li>
<li><a href="/update/mirrors.php">Download Game</a></li>
<li><a href="/levels/index.php">Download Levels</a></li>
<li><a href="/lb/view.php">View Leaderboards</a></li>
<li><a href="/infotutorial/index.php">Info/Tutorials</a> </li>
<li><a href="/about.php">Contact Locations/About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
body {
background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
ul.welcomeguest li a {
min-width:150px;
min-height:50px;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:50px;
white-space:nowrap;
float:left;
background:url(http://marbleblastultra.tk/images/button_d.png) no-repeat center;
background-size:100% 100%;
padding:0 20px;
}
.welcomeguest li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: outside none none;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mh70zn34/11/
Note: Can't use padding with percent value in your layout.